# How to detect all the urls of a website?

Tags: url, web

I wonder how to detect all the urls of a specified website, let's say, I know the website of https://stackoverflow.com/, how can I know that it has some urls  like https://stackoverflow.com/questions and https://stackoverflow.com/tags, is there a method or a tool to know the result?

Answer (score 0):

There are some possibilities:

1. If u don't want to write code you can use something like **Xenu** or **Webspider** to scan or save a website.
2. If you want to use it as part of your own tool you can write it in PHP:
   Directory listening on foreign server is on:

   `$dir = "stackoverflow.com/";
   foreach(scandir($dir) as $file){
     print '<a href="'.$dir.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br>';
   }`
3. Directory listening is of:
   Then you need to open the site per `php_get_contents` and filter for links per `preg_match`.

Comment: By the third method, do you mean get the content by using php_get_contents and then find all the urls with the help of preg_match, I think this is somewhat impossible, it's kind of a search engine's work.